# Subharmonic Functions on Closed Manifolds are Constant?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian, compact-manifolds

Apologies in advance if this question is trivial!

Let M be a closed, connected, oriented, n-dimensional, manifold without boundary.

Let $f$ be a smooth function on M where $\Delta f \geq 0$, where $\Delta$ is the Laplacian.

From this, show that $f$ is a constant function.

What I have tried:

$\Delta f = dd^*f + d^*df$

= $dd^*f = d^*[ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} dx_i ]$

But I am not sure where to go from here, or if this is even the right direction. My end goal is to show that $Df = 0$, I am just really unsure on how to connect $\Delta f \geq 0$ to $f$ being constant. Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: I guess you also wan the manifold to be connected for this to be true.

Comment: Please, modify the title by replacing the word "smooth" with "subharmonic".

Comment: Hint: Use the Maximum Principle for subharmonic functions on Riemannian manifolds.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1353699/show-that-a-nonconstant-subharmonic-function-on-a-manifold-cannot-attain-its-sup

Answer (score 2):

One way to prove this is via the maximum principle as Moishe Kohan mentions in the comments. Here is another way: Since $f$ is smooth it is bounded. Let $u = f-\inf_M f$. Then $\Delta v \geqslant 0$ and $v\geqslant 0$. It follows that $$0\leqslant \int_M v \Delta v\,d\mu_g =-\int_M \vert \nabla v \vert^2 \, d\mu_g \leqslant 0.$$ Hence, $$  \int_M \vert \nabla v \vert^2 \, d\mu_g=0,$$ so $v$ and consequently $f$ is constant.